# Is $f(x)$ the restriction to $\Bbb R$ of a function $f(z)$ holomorphic in the strip $S_a=\{z\in\Bbb C:|\operatorname{Im}(z)|<a\}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis

[image]
The above page is from *Complex Analysis* by Stein.

In Theorem 3.1, we denote the function $f(z)$ holomorphic in the strip $S_b$ by $f_b$.
When $0＜\alpha＜\beta＜a$, because $f_{\alpha}|_{\Bbb R}=f_{\beta}|_{\Bbb R}=f(x)$, therefore $f_{\beta}|_{S_{\alpha}}=f_{\alpha}$, we have $\bigcup_{0<b<a}f_b$ holomorphic in $S_a$, then $f(x)$ is the restriction to $\Bbb R$ of a function $f(z)$ holomorphic in the strip $S_a=\{z\in\Bbb C:|\operatorname{Im}(z)|<a\}$, isn't it?

Comment: I don't understand what is your question. The decay condition implies the Fourier inversion integral converges and is holomorphic and analytic for $|\Im(z)|< a$. Why Stein looked at $|\Im(z)|< a-\epsilon$ ? Because there the convergence is uniform so we can use the theorem he proved before about sequences of holomorphic-analytic-entire functions converging uniformly

Comment: @reuns You can scan my question again.

Comment: Please clarify what is unclear to you, in Stein and in what I said.

Comment: @reuns Why doesn't Stein say $f(x)$ is the restriction to $\Bbb R$ of a function $f(z)$ holomorphic in the strip $S_a=\{z\in\Bbb C:|\operatorname{Im}(z)|<a\}$?

Comment: I answered to that. It is what he says, to show it he looks at $|\Im(z)| < a - \epsilon$ where the integral converges **uniformly**, since the integrand is analytic, so is the limit : $f(z)$, by things like Morera's theorem

Comment: I think "f(x) is the restriction to R of a function f(z) holomorphic in the strip Sa" is indeed a consequence of this theorem (4.3.1) together with the identity theorem (2.4.8).

Comment: @JunyanXu Thank you very much!